# Decode (No Image) DataMatrix in PDF with zXing and PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, zxing, pdfbox

I need to decode a DataMatrix in a PDF, in my case the DataMatrix it's not a image.

My first idea was transform the Page to a Image and crop the area with the DataMatrix and after decode, but it seems the (image)result it's corrupted and I can't decode properly. Any idea How I can keep the quality of the PDF??

```
String sourceDir = "data/test2.pdf";

        File pdf = new File(sourceDir);

        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(sourceDir); 

        List<PDPage> list = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();

        String key;
        for (PDPage page : list) {

            BufferedImage image = page.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 300);

            BufferedImage dest = image.getSubimage(0, 2600, 800, 800);

            File outputFile = new File( "data/test2.jpg");
            ImageIO.write(dest, "png", outputFile);

            LuminanceSource lumSource = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource (dest);
            BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(lumSource));

            Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object> hint = new Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object>();
            hint.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX);

            DataMatrixReader DMreader = new DataMatrixReader();

            try {

            Result result = DMreader.decode(bitmap, hint);

            System.out.println(result);

            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("NO Data Matrix");

            }

                }


            }
```

Version 2.0

```
  PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(sourceDir));
        PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);

        for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++page)
        {
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, 600, ImageType.RGB);
            BufferedImage datamatrixImg = bufferedImage.getSubimage(150, 6000, 600, 900);

            File outputfile = new File("out/image_"+page+".jpg");
            ImageIO.write(datamatrixImg, "jpg", outputfile);

            LuminanceSource lumSource = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(datamatrixImg);
            BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(lumSource));

            Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object> hint = new Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object>();
            hint.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX);

            DataMatrixReader DMreader = new DataMatrixReader();

            try {
                Result result = DMreader.decode(bitmap, hint);
                System.out.println("Decode: "+ result );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("No DataMatrix");
            }
        }
        document.close();
```

Comment: 1) Please try again with the 2.x version, you're using an older version (read the migration guide at https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html ) 2) Why are you saving into a .jpg file in "png" format?? 3) if it still doesn't work, please share the PDF.

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr, 1) ok I did, 2) the saving file was only for testing 3)It works but I had to increase the resolution to 600 dpi, but even was working with the version 1.8 same trick doing a increment in the resolution. My question is there is another better way with better performance. We are working with vectors in the end mus be a way to extrac the vector and transform in a BufferImage for zxing..

Comment: You could make the code bigger. I don't have a better idea because you insist on using vectors (instead of an image). But is is kindof weird that apparently you're both creating and reading the barcode. Why not use a form field instead?

Comment: One thing to try would be to save not to ImageType.RGB, but to ImageType.BINARY. Another thing to try, if you know in advance the location of the barcode, would be to setCropBox() in the PDPage that has the location and size of the code. (1 unit = 1/72 inch). If you modify the PDF, then do this trick on a second PDDocument, or restore the cropBox after rendering.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I think same like you It will be much better with a image, but in our process we receive the pdf from another server who create this datamatrix like a vector, no chance to change this.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I did a test with Binary, in time the same pdf with RGB was: 8s and Binary 14s, I think for my case it's better the performance with  RGB.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, How I can transform the cropbox to a bufferImage?                 PDPage pageTest = document.getPage(1);
                PDRectangle rectangle = new PDRectangle(20, 20, 500, 600);
                pageTest.setCropBox(rectangle);

Comment: My suggestion about using BINARY wasn't about the time, it is about trying lower resolutions. Re cropbox, just render the image like you did before, i.e. `pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page,...);`